# Need azure devops help creating new branches in existing repo with local code, not based off of existing branches

Tags: c#, git, azure, visual-studio

So, test engineering software at my company has not been supported or version controlled efficiently for years, and software at specific  test benches has been held together by tape and bandaid fixes.

Around a dozen tools all operate on the same base project/solution (let’s call this TestCode) however each test benches version of TestCode has become relatively severed and independent from one another, and there is tons of incompatibility and unshared features (inadvertently). It is however all the same language C# and base code just different features and functionality here and there.

We have created an Azure Devops repository and branch based off of one of the test benches code, and now we aspire to make a branch for the next tool, ultimately slowly bringing the code back together over time.

**The problem is, we do not want to create these branches based off of the one branch we started the repo with. We want to use each test benches local code as a starting point for its corresponding branch.**

I imagined this would be easy, and maybe I am missing something, but I am seriously struggling to create a new repo branch in the existing repository based off of a local (C: drive) solution.

Is this possible? This would be the easiest way forward while also keeping all tools operational

Comment: The idea behind branches is that they are branched off from something, the root. I think in your case the easiest thing to do would be to create a new branch off of your Azure DevOps repo, and then overwrite this with the other not-version-controlled 'branch'. When you have all your code in source control, then slowly start merging these branches.

Comment: @T.vanSchagen this is my overdue thanks. I ended up doing exactly this, and we eventually got all the tools as well as a few new/separate ones operating on the same version of updated software which is nice. Thanks for the advice